# Compiler bug? "not a valid win32 application"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

I have been working on a very large program, compiling, testing, adding new code, compiling testing - repeat. The program has generally been working fine, but then I added some new code and now when I run the executable, I get a dialog box with "xxx.exe is not a valid Win32 application.", I can only assume this is a bug in the compiler. Has anyone had a problem like this before? Any idea how to work around it or find out what caused it?

**EDIT:** The program works fine when compiled as "Debug".

**EDIT:** **SOLVED:** shut down the compiler, started it again, rebuilt the exe, now it all works. I have no idea why... just one of those things...

Comment: What happens if you revert the changes you made to the code?  What was the code that caused your application to stop working?

Comment: What kind of application? Are you using a framework like Qt? Are there any special post build / resource compile steps that could mess with the application?

Comment: unfortunately it was quite a complex edit involving lots of different source files. I don't use version control software so going backwards is a bit messy... but I am experimenting now... one moment please...

Comment: The software is a strategy game. I am not using Qt. The changes comprised adding some diagnostic code.

Comment: @Mick: start using source control, now!

Comment: @xtofl: I tried some version control software a few years ago and then abandoned it. It was so complex and I needed to use it so infrequently that I decided it was more trouble than it was worth. It's just me working on the program.

Comment: @Mick: without being a nag: version control can be simple, and _is_ terribly useful and worth the effort!  It can be as simple as `hg init; hg add; hg commit`, and you have a snapshot of your state-of-the-art, compiling, working, code.  Nowadays vcsses integrate well with windows explorer, Visual Studio, ...

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you mistakenly set target platform to x64 or IA64? That would cause such an error message when attempting to run the app.

Did you try a clean+build (or full rebuild)?

Comment: I didn't set a target of x64 or IA64. I did clean+build.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use inline assembly, or specify a specific target CPU in your compiler settings?

In either of those case, it's perhaps possible the compiler is generating instructions for the wrong CPU.

Comment: There is no inline assembly. I don't think I have set any CPU specific compilation options and anyway I have not changed the compiler options recently.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this by messing around with function calling conventions. Check that.